# How can I open a URL from an image printed on paper?

Tags: scanning

I have a survey and I would like to distribute flyers with a QR code linking the survey. But lots of people dont have a QR code reader where I live.

What else can I do so the flyer redirects for the survey easily?

Comment: What kind of hardware do the people you target have? For instance, do you usually have Android or iOS smartphones? Or do they usually have paper and pen, and a desktop computer at home? Or do they just have their brain memory and no access to any computer device at all?

Comment: Edit your question to clarify then ask me to reopen. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem already, no need to reopen it

Answer (score 2):

You can use a URL shortener like https://goo.gl/ to reduce the number of characters a user needs to type.

Comment: ...or just simple use (means redirect) a subdomain like http://survey.domain.tld to your survey (if you own a domain).

Answer (score 0):

Use a QR code

[image]

There's a few websites that will generate a URL to QR, such as: http://goqr.me/

Comment: Asker specifically says no QR codes.

Answer (score 0):

Other than typing the URL (e.g. shortened like *porton* answered), you can't really do this without an app.

You could try [Layar](https://www.layar.com/). It's hard to read through the marketing jargon on their site to find out what it does, but basically it lets you photograph objects (in your case that would be pages) and then link an action to that (in your case, visiting a URL).

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZR4eSmmPCxg) will give you an idea of what it does.